# Logstash configuration file error(Answer not working)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

The only thing that is certain about [url][queryString] is that it begins with 404; or that the key is long.I need to remove such keys.
If I use the ruby code below it gives cannot convert linked hashmap to string exception.

```
input {
    file {
        # Wildcards work, here :)
        path => ["C:\Users\ppurush\Desktop\test\*.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code=>
        "
        require json
        my_hash = JSON.parse([url][queryString])
        my_hash.delete_if { |key,value| key.to_s.match(/^404;/) }
        "
    }
}

output {
    stdout{}
    elasticsearch {
       host => localhost
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the errors you're seeing and maybe a few sample log lines that you're indexing?

Comment: This is the error I am getting "@version" => "1",
             "path" => "C:/Users/ppurush/Desktop/test/test.log",
             "tags" => [
        [0] "_rubyexception"
    ]
}
{

Answer (score 0):

You get a **ruby exception** because your ruby code is invalid. Try this instead:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        init => "require 'json'"
        code => "
            my_hash = JSON.parse( event['url']['queryString'] )
            my_hash.delete_if { |key,value| key.to_s.match(/^404;/) }
        "
    }
}
```

This works if your event has a `'url' => 'queryString'` field which contains valid json. You might already have some kind of filter to achieve this (e.g. [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)). You might also consider using logstash's built-in [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) and maybe [drop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) to delete certain events.

---

### EDIT:

Suppose your input is plain json (I had to tidy this up):

```
{"id":"val1","host":"val2","app":"val3","@timestamp":"2015-08-04T19:00:03.642932‌​2Z","@timestampEnd":"2015-08-04T19:00:03.6429322Z","vid":"val4","vidNew":"val5","se‌​ssionId":"val6","url":{"rawUrl":"val7","path":"val8","queryString":{"404;dfdgfdgf‌​ghfhjghhhhhhhhhhhhh":""}},"net":{"method":"GET","status":"200","size":"0","timeTa‌​kenMillis":"0"},"context":{"SearchType":""}}
```

You can use `codec => "json"` in your file input.

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["C:\Users\ppurush\Desktop\test\*.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => "json"
    }
}
```

You will get a field:

```
"url" => {
         "rawUrl" => "val7",
           "path" => "val8",
    "queryString" => {
        "404;dfdgfdgf‌​ghfhjghhhhhhhhhhhhh" => ""
    }
}
```

So `404;dfdgfdgf‌​ghfhjghhhhhhhhhhhhh` is a variable, too. To check for it and delete the event you could do something like this:

```
if [url][queryString][404;dfdgfdgf‌​ghfhjghhhhhhhhhhhhh] {
        drop {}
    }
```

Comment: {"id":"val1","host":"val2","app":"val3","@timestamp":"2015-08-04T19:00:03.6429322Z","@timestampEnd":"2015-08-04T19:00:03.6429322Z","vid":"val4","vidNew":val5,"sessionId":"val6","url":{"rawUrl":"val7","path":"val8","queryString":{"404;dfdgfdgfghfhjghhhhhhhhhhhhh":""}},"net":{"method":"GET","status":"200","size":"0","timeTakenMillis":"0"},"context":{"SearchType":""}    This is one log entry line. querystring..So will it work?

Comment: I haven't used grok. I didn't understand usage of grok that well. How will I specify such an entry using grok? I also tried using kv filter as I need to extract the key in [url][queryString] and check if it starts with 404. I could'nt extract the key.

Comment: I tried it with this code. But I still get an exception

Comment: You input is plain json. You neither need grok nor a ruby filter for this. See my edit.

Comment: Will this work??                                                                                               if [url][queryString][/^404;/] {
        drop {}
    }

Comment: There seem more bogus keys. The only common thing in them is that they have a long length. Can I use regular expression to do it??

Comment: dfdgfdgf‌​ghfhjghhhhhhhhhhhhh is variable junk data.